# How To remove the English Tag from the WPML if the code is not added manually by us

Tags: wpml, hreflang

In my Website the two x-default tags are there because the home page url is in english and the two tags one for "en" and another one for x-default both pointing to the same url and that's why the two x-defaluts are there in my website.

Now I want to remove the en tag because x-default is enough so the problem is that the code is added manually it is added by WPML how can we remove the en tag.

Please let me know the exact way to remove the "en" tag from the WPML.

I will Try to remove the en tag but not done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.